# Show custom xaxis in highchart with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

i need to create custom xaxis shown in this image in highcharts with angular[image] .

in plain JS in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxbso624/1/) I am able to achieve it, I tried same chart options in angular  but i am getting like this, Can someone help me on what i did wrong?
[image],

[stackblitz link for angular](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-demo-xqlh5t)

Comment: Please [edit] the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import and initialize the `highcharts-grouped-categories` module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-grouped-categories

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsGroupedCategories from 'highcharts-grouped-categories';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

HighchartsGroupedCategories(Highcharts);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-demo-4y3css?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhighcharts.service.ts

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-module